# Entity Framework Code First Include Method and missing Navigation Property

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I have the following (abbreviated) DbContext:

```cs
public class O19Context : BaseContext<O19Context>
{
    public DbSet<PRJ> O19Set { get; set; }
}

[Table("AUFK")]
public class AUFK
{
  [ForeignKey("PRJ_GUID")]
  public PRJ PRJ {get; set;}
  [Key]
  public Guid AUFK_GUID {get; set;}
}

[Table("PRJ")]
public class PRJ
{
  [Key]
  public Guid PRJ_GUID {get; set;}
  public IQueryable<AUFK> AUFKS {get; set;}
}
```

When I run the following code:

```
var db = new O19Context();
var prj = db.O19Set.Include("AUFKS")
    .Single(o => o.PRJ_GUID ==
        new Guid("6FE5E97B-9970-4E24-B051-9A710C03A030"));
```

I get an invalid Include path error.  The EntityType PRJ does not declare a navigation property with the name AUFKS.

Where am I going wrong?
Pamela

Comment: But AUFKS is defined within PRJ not O19Content   .   Is that a cut and paste error ?

Comment: It could be called a cut and paste error.  I probably should have pasted the PRJ table before the AUFK table to be less confusing.  But AUFK is defined as a child of PRJ.

Comment: `IQueryable<>` is an interface that doesn't define write methods, Entity Framework is simply ignoring it then. you should change the collection type to a writeable one like `HashSet`, `ICollection`, `IList` etc.

Answer (score 2):

A good way to see if EF likes your POCO is the EF Power Tools "View Entity Data Model (Read Only)".

http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/10/ef-power-tools-beta4

I made two changes to your code and it now creates a little diagram...

[image: EF Power Tools diagram]

```
[TestClass]
public class O19Tests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void O19Test1()
    {
        var db = new O19Context();

        var prj = db.O19Set.Include("AUFKS")
            .FirstOrDefault(o => o.PRJ_GUID ==
                new Guid("6FE5E97B-9970-4E24-B051-9A710C03A030"));
    }
}

public class O19Context : DbContext//<O19Context>
{
    public DbSet<PRJ> O19Set { get; set; }
}

[Table("AUFK")]
public class AUFK
{
    //[ForeignKey("PRJ_GUID")] //remove this... 
    //there is no PRJ_GUID field IN THIS CLASS
    public PRJ PRJ { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public Guid AUFK_GUID { get; set; }
}

[Table("PRJ")]
public class PRJ
{
    [Key]
    public Guid PRJ_GUID { get; set; }
    public IList<AUFK> AUFKS { get; set; } //use IList
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I have a tough time figuring out which interface to implement for which scenario.  I had originally used IList, but I was getting errors from EF on some of my queries.  Might be a good topic for a book.

Answer (score 0):

A navigation property must implement `ICollection<T>` - you define the property as `IQueryable<T>` which I do not believe is supported